# Can't get Messenger Bot approved

Tags: bots, messenger, facebook-messenger

I have sent my messenger bot for approval and I always get the request rejected with this message: **"Please provide a test url that we can test with."**. It's a messenger bot that works in a Facebook page chat, there is no link to provide... Obviously I have selected my page where my bot correctly reply to me... What can I do? Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the URL to your webhook.

Comment: Open a question in the https://developers.facebook.com, in Tools&Support section and ask the same question which you have asked here. Probably it is a mistake in their review team. I had similar experience. My bot was rejected with no sense and after opening a question they had approved.